# How to substitute HttpServletResponse output stream?

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets

I need to use JSP to generate a HTML report. I made an example, but it does not work in Tomcat6 so far.

```
public class SubstitutionServlet extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    protected void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/jsp/report.jsp");
        final ByteArrayOutputStream buf = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ServletResponseWrapper wrapper = new HttpServletResponseWrapper(response){
            @Override
            public PrintWriter getWriter() throws IOException {
                return new PrintWriter(buf);
            }
        };
        dispatcher.forward(request, wrapper);
        String html = buf.toString("UTF-8"); // "" is returned
        System.out.println(html);
        response.getOutputStream().print("Completed");
    }
}
```

When I try to run this example, I get an empty string as a result. What mistake have I made?

Comment: Your stream wasn't flushed which could be a problem and you should close the stream when you finished writing. This could solve your problem.

Comment: You haven't done anything useful with `buf`. You've printed it to `System.out`, i.e. the log file, but you haven't written it to the response output stream. And you can't, because you've forwarded to something else. What exactly are you trying to do here? It doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that you were creating new `PrintWriter` for every invocation of method `getWriter`. Instead you should have one and reuse it.

```
public class SubstitutionServlet extends HttpServlet {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Override
 protected void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
     RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/jsp/report.jsp");
     final ByteArrayOutputStream buf = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
     final PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(buf); //CREATE ONLY ONE WRITER
     ServletResponseWrapper wrapper = new HttpServletResponseWrapper(response) {
         @Override
         public PrintWriter getWriter() throws IOException {
             return out; // REUSE WRITER
         }
     };
     dispatcher.forward(request, wrapper);
     String html = buf.toString("UTF-8"); // "" is returned
     System.out.println(html);
     response.getOutputStream().print("Completed");
   }
}
```

Comment: I had to call out.flush() before buf.toString("UTF-8") for this to work.